# How to output an int in a JOptionPane dialogue box?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was wondering how you display a messagebox that shows an int. For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ShowMessage {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 4;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a  );
```

I get an error under the `showMessageDialog`.

Comment: what is the error? work for me

Comment: Convert the `int` to `String`, `Integer.toString` for example...

Comment: First, take a look at the requirements for [`JOptionPane#showMessageDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-), the message parameter is a `Object`, `int` is a primitive

Comment: The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (null, int)

Comment: @MadProgrammer above code work for me ..is it possible ?

Comment: @FastSnail The OP's code didn't work for me (the first time I tried, wonder what I did wrong), possibly they are using a version of Java before autoboxing or that's not the real problem...was wondering about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the JavaDocs for [`JOptionPane#showMessageDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-), you will see that message parameter is a `Object` while `int` is a primitive

Prior to Java 5's autoboxing support you would have had to convert `a` to `Integer`, but

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, a);
```

Should work.  `JOptionPane` will use the object's (now a `Integer`) `toString` method to create a `String` representation for you, but personally I prefer to use

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Integer.toString(a));
```

as it's intentions are well spelled out without people needing to know how the underlying `JOptionPane` API works

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't know how to toString the integer properly. Also how do I connect the int a to a string? JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Integer.toString(a)) + "People"; And also, how do I make it so the messagebox displays after a scanner. IE: int b = something.nextInt();

Comment: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Integer.toString(a) + " People")` - Simple string concatenation. *"And also, how do I make it so the messagebox displays after a scanner. IE: int b = something.nextInt();"* ... put it after the request for information from the user...

Comment: I had some formatting errors for the string concatenation so I had it right the entire time. I can't put the messagebox after the request for the user to enter information because I have scanners and variables after it. It's weird because system.out.println still works even if there's a lot of variables above it.

Comment: Without a runnable example of what you're trying to do, it's hard to advise

Comment: Sorry, System.out.print("Please enter the number of people ");
 double people = scan.nextDouble();
 System.out.print("Please enter the number of tables: ");
 double tables = scan.nextDouble(); 
 
 if(people>10)
 {
   table++
 }
 JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null, Interger.toString(table) + "tables"); EDIT: sorry, idk how to format comments

Comment: `table` should be `tables`, `Interger` should be `Integer`, you've missed a semi colon at after `table++;` (which should be `tables++`) and because `tables` is a `double`, you can't use `Integer`, but would need `Double` or a `NumberFormat`

Comment: I didn't copy and paste it I just typed up a hypothetical but had the same components of what I was trying to do. But I can't get the messagebox to appear.

Comment: Well, the flow looks alright, assuming your not getting any errors from the `Scanner`.  Perhaps you should put together a complete runnable example and ask a new question